# Failed to configure trigger providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.update

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I plan on updating the news_author_user_type every time an update happens on user_type in users node

Here's my code

```
exports.onUpdateUserType = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{user_id')
    .onUpdate((change, context) => {
        const newUserDoc = change.after.data();
        const user_type = newUserDoc.user_type;
        const user_id = context.auth.uid;

        const db = admin.firestore();
        const newsRef = db.collection('news').where('news_author_id', '==', user_id);
        const news =  newsRef.get().then(onSnapshot => {
            onSnapshot.forEach(result => {
                const news_id = result.id;
                const newsDoc = db.doc(`news/${news_id}`);
                const news_author_type = {
                    news_author_type:user_type
                };
                newsDoc.update(news_author_type).then(onUpdate => {
                    return onUpdate;
                }).catch(onErrorUpdate => {
                    return onErrorUpdate;
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Check the de function trigger have a typo.

```
functions.firestore.document('users/{user_id')
```

This should be:

```
functions.firestore.document('users/{user_id}')
```

Answer (score 8):

Check the function trigger have a typo.

```
functions.firestore.document('users/{doc-id}')
```

This should be:

```
functions.firestore.document('users/{id}')
```

Hyphens do not allow the functions deploy properly

Answer (score 6):

**Future readers**

Also make sure you're not using `$` character with your wildcard (which I accidentally did).

`functions.firestore.document('users/${user_id}')`

(Notice the `$` sign which should not be present)

This should be:

`functions.firestore.document('users/{user_id}')`

It's not a JS template literal

Comment: I believe that $ was for the template literal. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Correct a JS template literal is what I meant, it's a mistake I've done a few times as they look so similar, so thought I'd mention it here for people encountering the same error.

Answer (score 4):

```
exports.achievements = functions.firestore.document("notifications/{any}/{any}/{any}").onCreate((snap, context) => {
```

In my case i changed `"notifications/{any}/{any}/{any}"` to: `"notifications/{anyday}/{anytype}/{anydoc}"`

Answer (score 2):

For Readers, Also keep in mind the path to the documents for example

```
/users/{id}/employee/{id}
```

can not have the same path variable name, instead change it to something else
like `/users/{userId}/employee/{employeeId}`. Fixed my issue with deploying firebase functions

Comment: Saved my day. I wonder why this answer has no upvotes. No one did this mistake. :P

Answer (score 0):

Also double check if you have any authentication (email, anonymous, google, whatever) activated as it will give the same error if you have nothing activated yet.