# Error deploying Firebase function: Each then() should return a value or throw promise/always-return

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, eslint

I have tried common solutions recommended in similar posts such as returning null, or retuning a non-null value but that just results in another deployment error as follows:

Failed to configure trigger providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.create@firestore.googleapis.com....

I am using eslint as well. My function code is as follows:

```
exports.onCreateActivityFeedItem = functions
    .firestore
    .document('/feed/{userId}/feedItems/{activityFeedItem')
    .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
        console.log('Activity Feed Item Create', snapshot.data());

        // 1) Get user connected to the feed
        const userId = context.params.userId;
        const userRef = admin.firestore().doc(`users/${userId}`);
        const doc = await userRef.get();

        // 2) Once we have user, check if the have notification token
        //send notification if they have a token
        const androidNotificationToken = doc.data().androidNotificationToken;
        const createdActivityFeedItem = snapshot.data();

        if(androidNotificationToken){
            //send the notification
            sendNotification(androidNotificationToken, createdActivityFeedItem);
        }else{
            console.log("No token for user, cannot send notification");
        }

        function sendNotification(androidNotificationToken, activityFeedItem){
            let body;

            // 3) switch body value based off of notification type
            switch (activityFeedItem.type){
                case "comment":
                 body = `${activityFeedItem.username} replied: ${activityFeedItem.commentData}`;
                 break;
                case "like":
                 body = `${activityFeedItem.username} liked your post`;
                 break;
                case "follow":
                 body = `${activityFeedItem.username} started following your pet`;
                 break;
                default:
                 break;
            }

            // 4) Create message for push notification
            const message = {
                notification: { body },
                token: androidNotificationToken,
                data: { recipient: userId }
            };

            // 5) Send message with admin.messaging()
            admin
                .messaging()
                .send(message)
                .then(response => {
                    // Response is a message ID string
                    console.log("Successfully sent message", response);
                    //return 1;   //Last edition trying to fix bug

                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log("Error sending message", error);
                });
        }
});
```

Comment: Please narrow your question down to a single issue.  You are citing two problems here, one with eslint, and another with the creation of the trigger.  These two issues might not be related to each other.  It will be helpful if you create an MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
admin
            .messaging()
            .send(message)
            .then(response => {
                // Response is a message ID string
                console.log("Successfully sent message", response);
                //return 1;   //Last edition trying to fix bug

            }).catch(error => {
                console.log("Error sending message", error);
            });
    }
```

Into this:

```
return admin
            .messaging()
            .send(message)
            .then(response => {
                // Response is a message ID string
                console.log("Successfully sent message", response);
               // return 1;   //Last edition trying to fix bug

            }).catch(error => {
                console.log("Error sending message", error);
            });
    }
```

Also you are missing `}` in the `document`:

Change:
 `document('/feed/{userId}/feedItems/{activityFeedItem')`

Into this:

`document('/feed/{userId}/feedItems/{activityFeedItem}')`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The above suggestion results in the same error: Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return

Comment: Uncomment the return 1 and change it to return null

Comment: Trying that (returning null) results in the deployment error: (Failed to configure trigger providers/cloud.firestore...). Also tried returning 1 ad it gives the same error

Comment: Change `document('/feed/{userId}/feedItems/{activityFeedItem')` into this `document('/feed/{userId}/feedItems/{activityFeedItem} ')`

Comment: That still gives the same deployment error: (Failed to configure trigger providers/cloud.firestore...)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52447445/failed-to-configure-trigger-providers-cloud-firestore-eventtypes-document-update

Comment: Final Solution: Just needed to return inside both the then() function as well as the catch(), and that finally resulted in a successful deployment. Thanks for the comments Peter Hadad